# Errors and warnings in Xcode4

Tags: xcode4

I think this is just a bug in Xcode4.

When I click an error showed in the issue navigator, Xcode shows the line that contains the error in the editor view. But in some projects, Xcode opens the file that contains the error but never scroll to the line. It wastes my time and energies away a lot everytime...

It seems that some specific codes may cause this problem, but I can't figure out what it is. Anyone knows what may cause this problem or avoid it?